# How to increase line spacing in TikZ node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, line-spacing

In the code below, how can I increase line spacing in the node?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\node (example-align) [draw,align=left,text width=8cm] at (5,-5) {\lipsum[1]};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @LaRiFaRi: I saw it before. It doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: if `\node (example-align) [draw,align=left,text width=8cm] at (5,-5) {\baselineskip=16pt\lipsum[1]};` does not work for you, you will have to update your system or expand your MWE to the actual problem. Or I do not understand the issue you are having. Please clarify.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi: Wow, it does! Thanks. please post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can define the `\baselineskip` in the inner of your node:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \node (1) [draw,align=left,text width=2cm, anchor=north] at (1,0) {\baselineskip=10pt\lipsum[1]};
    \node (2) [draw,align=left,text width=2cm, anchor=north] at (4,0) {\baselineskip=12.5pt\lipsum[1]};
    \node (3) [draw,align=left,text width=2cm, anchor=north] at (7,0) {\baselineskip=15pt\lipsum[1]};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And a tip: If one wants to replace `\lipsum[1]` with real text, he/she **must** enter a `\par` after the end of the real text.

Comment: If `text width` is not set, then the `\baselineskip` setting only works if it is set in the tikz style of the node: `\tikz \node[align=left, execute at begin node=\setlength{\baselineskip}{5ex}] {foo\\bar};`